# Reactjs Handle State Change - Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, state

I am updating initial state based on onchange event passed by textboxes to event handler , as below -

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'

function ViewAll() {
    const iCandidateState={
        Name:'',
        Age:'',
        Qalification:''
    };
    function nameHandler(event){
        alert(event.target.value);
        this.iCandidateState.Name=event.target.value;
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <table>
              <tr>
                  <td>
                      Name
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <input type="text" name="txtName" value={iCandidateState.Name} onChange={(e)=>nameHandler(e)}></input> 
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>
                      Age
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <input type="text" name="txtAge"></input> 
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>
                      Qalification
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <input type="text" name="txtQualification"></input> 
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td colSpan="2" align="center">
                     <button name="btnSubmitForm">Post</button>
                  </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ViewAll
```

When I type something in txtName , I expect state - iCandidateState to get updated with Name field within textbox. But I am getting an error - `TypeError: Cannot read property 'iCandidateState' of undefined`

I also tried this with setState as -

```
 this.setState({
                ...iCandidateState,
                Name:event.target.value
            })
```

After typing something in textbox I get error as -

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
```

How can I update the state ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed up the idea of class components and functional components. The `this` syntax is for class components, i.e.

```
class ViewAll extends Component {

  render() {
    return (/* some components */);
  }
}
```

You are trying to create a functional component (denoted by the keyword `function`). So you should use [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) instead. It should be something like

```
import { useState } from 'react'

function ViewAll() {
  const [iCandidateState, setICandidateState] = useState({
    Name: '',
    Age: '',
    Qalification: ''
  });

  function nameHandler(event) {
    alert(event.target.value);
    setCandState({ ...iCandidateState, Name: event.target.value })
  }

  return (/* some components */);
}

export default ViewAll
```

Comment: Got you Matthew , one should not use 'this' with functional components and should make use of hooks. This is helpful.

Comment: This line code maybe cause the bugs `setICandidateState(event.target.value);` Pls note that the diferent between `setState` - merge and `useState` - replace. So it should be `setCandState({ ...iCandidateState, Name: event.target.value })`

Answer (score 3):

In a function component, you can't use this. Instead, you can use useState hook to handle this problem. Please replace the corresponding part of your code with this

```
const [iCandidateState, setCandState] = useState({
    Name: '',
    Age: '',
    Qalification: ''
});

function nameHandler(event) {
    alert(event.target.value);
    setCandState({
        ...iCandidateState,
        Name: event.target.value,
    })
}
```